# Repository Setup Hierarchy for Demo and acceptance in Enterprise

Tags: registry, wso2, directory, structure

I am new to the Ws02 gov. repository. We are evaluating if the WSO2 gov. repository will fit into our enterprise needs.

I have the basic empty registry setup on a server with nothing in it now. I need to setup a organizational hierarchy structure including applications/programs/projects/processes/technical and business services etc in the registry and then add some real-world content from our existing projects into the registry so that we can present it to senior management and get acceptance.

Is there a quick-start and standard or sample registry structure I could use to do this quickly. We need to present the output to our global CIO next week for acceptance.

We are a very large enterprise (more than 50K users globally) so need a very compelling demo to get acceptance and move forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following guides might be helpful..

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/design-time-governace-using-wso2greg/

http://wso2.com/library/articles/soa-governance-wso2-registry-v1-1/

http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/01/governing-enterprise-assets-wso2-governance-registry/